# Conditional selection in stored procedure PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've created a stored procedure to search for employee names, however I want it open ended so that the user can insert a first or last name, or no name at all.. just wondering how to structure the logic for this.

Basically something like below.. I want it to skip past the check for a name if it's null. Should the line below work? Or have I messed up. Thanks.

```
search_employe(name, type)

SELECT * FROM employee_table e
WHERE e.type = type
AND IF name is not null THEN e.FNAME = name OR e.LName = name END IF
AND {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection doesn't need any plsql, but the original post talks about 'insert', so that may need some clarification - do you mean, pass the parameter?

```
SELECT * FROM employee_table e
WHERE e.type = type
AND (name is null OR e.FNAME = name OR e.LName = name)
```

I think it makes very little sense / very confusing to have a stored procedure where the caller passes in a name to be matched, but you are also to return any employee who has no name registered against them, and consider that a match. If you really want to return such confusing data (QA will have a field day) then it can be done:

```
SELECT * FROM employee_table e
WHERE e.type = type
AND 
(
    -- matching names, or the value was passed in null
    (name is null OR e.FNAME = name OR e.LName = name)
    OR
    -- value passed in, but the employee has no registered name
    (name is not null AND e.FNAME is null AND e.LName is null)
)
```

But I really recommend that this goes back to the drawing board to understand the requirements and integrity of the data.

Comment: Hm, but what if name isn't null and the first/last name aren't known?

Comment: How / why would you be storing employees with an unknown first and last name? The same technique of using AND / OR conditions would work when written appropriately, you do not need an IF statement (or more precisely a case statement) in the query.

Comment: Well, if you had an Employee ID but not a name, suppose you could have multiple selects based on what type of search.

Comment: Whooops, to clarify, I meant if you didn't know their name, but had other criteria, such as start dates / employee id's. It's not going to bring back all records, as that'd cause issues.

Comment: If you didnt know their name, and send in a null name, then the name is null = true in the OR clause, and the whole of thats parens logic = true meaning the rows are not eliminated based on the null value sent in.

Comment: Ooh right, sorry I get it now. Thanks for explaining all this. I was definitely over complicating things using cases.